# Stretch Canvas to the size of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe

my task is to program a game with `128*128 px`. So I started to prepare the Game Java Framework and everything is fine: I've got a `JFrame` and inside of it is a Canvas where I can draw. But I can't set the sizes correctly. I **have to** work with `128*128 px` but if the frame would be the same size it would be way too small so I need to scale it up.

But If I scale the size of the Frame up, the Canvas is too small and doesn't fill it anymore. If I'd simply give it the same size as the Frame then I wouldn't work with `128*128 px` anymore. So how can I draw everything like normal onto my small canvas and scale it up afterwards?

```
package de.gaminggears.communitygame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import de.gaminggears.communitygame.display.Display;

public class Game implements Runnable{

private Display display;
public int width, height;
public String title;

private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;

private BufferStrategy bs;
private Graphics g;


public Game(String title,int width, int height){
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.title = title;

}

private void init(){
    display = new Display(title, width, height);
}

private void tick(){

}

private void render(){
    bs = display.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        display.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    //Clear Screen
    g2d.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    //Draw Here!

    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2d.fillRect(10, 50, 50, 70);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);

    //End Drawing

    g2d.scale(5, 5);
    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}

public void run(){

    init();

    while(running){
        tick();
        render();
    }
    stop();
}


public synchronized void start(){
    if(running)
        return;
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop(){
    if(!running)
        return;
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: It's easy with a `Graphics2D` object, just use [`scale(sx,sy)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#scale-double-double-) ..

Comment: But I dont want to scale everything object by object. I want to prepare the canvas like I'd like to have it and then simply scale everything up at the same time

Comment: *"But I dont want to scale everything object by object"*  That was the idea of what I was saying.  When it comes time to paint, pating on a single `Graphics2D` instances and draw everything to the same instance.  It will turn out as required.  This is the same technique I used to draw logos.  For printing they require 2000 x 2000 pixels, but that is hard to work with.  So I design them at 600 x 600 then when I'm happy with the result, I scale the whole thing up to the required size.  Easy!

Comment: ok thanks, I will try it like that and tell you if it worked or not :)

Comment: If you look at my Thread you'll see that I added a the code I have rn. It still draws the rectangles but the size is the same

Comment: The call to `g2d.scale(5, 5);` should be before ***any*** drawing is done to it!  But for more specific help, post a [mcve].